# Using Less Change a variable value every 0.5s

Tags: css, less

I have a global variable that is used all over the place `@temp-primary: #ff00ff;`
I am trying to use `LESS` to alternate the color globals every 0.5s. The `@temp-primary` variable is always assigned to `color:` throughout my website. How would I go about this? I know this can be some with css animations i just dont know hwo to achieve this using `less`.

I have gotten

```
@var: 'Math.random(6)';

@temp-primary: fade(darken(spin(#F0F, @var*156), 15%), 75%);
```

However this only randomizes the color and doesnt constantly change it

Comment: It's CSS... you can't do random.

Comment: @Mooseman Sorry let me clerify, I want the color to constantly change between a set of predefined colors

Comment: This you can do with a `keyframe` animation but that way you'd have to have predefined colors and the same repeating pattern each time. To make it random use javascript set Interval, `setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello change color code"); }, 500);`

Comment: @Callat Right i want it to be pure css, this is the path is tarted to take however the variable is assigned to many different classes through `color:` so assigning the animation didnt seem to work?

Comment: @Charles have you tried making a mixin that has the animation inside of it? Then applying that?

Comment: @Callat im not sure how to do such that, im to new to `less`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but I believe that this may be a resolution to your problem. This can't go in a comment so I'm adding it as an answer.

Here is the link to mixins: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

So we can have

```
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}
#animation{
   width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: example; 
    animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@temp-primary: #animation();
```

Should be doable.

As an alternate approach variable interpolation might be something you want to look into with less.

Here's a link to another SO post about something similar. 
I hope this helps.

[LESS - Assign mixin to variable and reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467560/less-assign-mixin-to-variable-and-reuse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)